# Move all the Team foundation server projects to bit-bucket?

Tags: c#, git, tfs, bitbucket

I'm currently using TFS to handle all the C# projects. However I need to switched to bit-bucket. Therefore is there any way to migrate all the team foundation server projects directly to bit-bucket? (I want to move all the projects at once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct import currently available on BitBucket to import repositories from a TFS server.
What you will need to do is bridge your TFS repositories from TFS to Git (with [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)
) and then push those new Git repositories to BitBucket.

If you want to do it all at once, you can always make a batch file that does all the steps for each project that you have

Answer (score 3):

A first step would be [converting your TFS repositories to local git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294894/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-tfs-project-to-a-git-repo#17295432). [Here's another relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874873/migrating-from-tfs-to-git). Be aware that any branches/tags you have will be lost in the process, unless you re-create them manually.

Then, you'd create a repository at bitbuket, and [setup your local repository to push to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570446/how-to-add-gitbitbucket-to-existing-source-code-folder).

AFAIK, there's no pre-existing solution to do this in multiple repositories at once, but it should be fairly easy to automate in the shell of your choice (powershell, batch file, bash, etc).